# How to use GeoPandas or Fiona to find the inner part of the polygon through subtraction?

Tags: polygon, geopandas, difference, subtraction, fiona

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWEpW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLLbf.png)

I am trying to find a way how we can get the upper part of the polygon (image 2) from the bigger polygon (image 1) using GeoPandas/Fiona functions. The other way round is quite easy by using the overlay set operation of "difference" but the way I want it, the functions/tools in GeoPandas does not work.

Comment: maybe share your polygons as WKT.   it's really not clear what you are asking from two unconnected images

Answer (score 0):

- simply you need https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html#
- you have not provided any geometry.  Have used Ukraine as larger geometry and a number of box geometries that overlap Ukraine
- full example below

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd
import geopy.distance
import numpy as np

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

dims = (10, 10)
a, b, c, d = world.loc[world["name"].eq("Ukraine")].total_bounds
g = .1
# generate some polygons and a line that cuts through some of the polygons
gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.box(minx + g, miny + g, maxx - g, maxy - g)
        for minx, maxx in zip(
            np.linspace(a, c, dims[0]), np.linspace(a, c, dims[0])[1:]
        )
        for miny, maxy in zip(
            np.linspace(b, d, dims[1]), np.linspace(b, d, dims[1])[1:]
        )
    ],
    crs="epsg:4326",
).sample(8, random_state=1)

big_without_small = world.loc[world["name"].eq("Ukraine")].overlay(gdf_grid, how="difference")
big_without_small.plot()
```

[image]